# what is triggering my server.js nodejs api?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to start my server by node server.js command on port 8060, but I'm getting below error:

```
REST API is runnning at 8060
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8060
```

when I did netstat `netstat -natp` I found server.js is already running on same port. When I tried to kill the process, the process appears with different pid. What is triggering command `node server.js`? 
Any help appreciated. Below are couple of snapshot:
[image]

2nd snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without further data, I'd suggest looking into your `systemd` (or which other long-running service manager works on your machine) and `nginx` configurations. I'm betting your process is being restarted on fail.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for comment. What further info might help you?
This is on cloud (digital ocean droplet) I'm having this issue. However, when I do it locally, it works fine and it never restarted the process on fail.

Comment: What linux distro and version are you running? Check out the man page for `ps` and invoke it with options `afx` or whichever options are used to select all processes and to include the process ownership information including the PPID field which will tell you the parent process Id of your restarting node processes. Depending on the identity of that process, I'll be able to help further.

Comment: I guess I got my answer @Rob after doing what you suggested.

>`Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
>Release: 16.04
>Codename: xenial


>root     30751  0.0 13.8 1187836 69360 ?       Ssl  Oct30   0:27 node /developement/project/server.js`


>**6563 ?        Ssl  254:48 PM2 v2.7.1: God Daemon (/root/.pm2)
>30751 ?        Ssl    0:27  \_ node /developement/project/server.js**

I cant remember during the setup when I added PM2 but thanks to you for helping when other chose to down vote. Appreciate that.